# Alpine Linux - root mounted as ro iso9660 filesystem how can I remount as rw overlay?

Tags: docker, filesystems, mount, alpine, overlayfs

The root filesystem is an iso9660 mount.

```
/ # mount |grep iso
/dev/sr0 on / type iso9660 (ro,relatime)
```

Is there a way to remount root, using aufs in order that I can install packages, compile code, etc?

Comment: Do you mean "Is there a way to remount root **read/write**"?

Comment: Hi Tom - I've clarified a little - I'm specifically looking to make a mount trick using aufs